# FTP does not work properly when connected to OpenVPN

Tags: ftp, iptables, openvpn

I am connected to an OpenVPN server and would like to list all files on a FTP server.

```
ftp> ls
500 I won't open a connection to 10.125.1.20 (only to 31.x.x.100)
ftp: bind: Address already in use
ftp>
```

The `tun` interface has the IP 10.125.1.20 and it seems my FTP client (which is the `ftp` command in Linux) reports that IP to the FTP server and not the IP provided by the OpenVPN server.

Can I make something with iptables forwarding to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're running your FTP client on an host that is connected to an OpenVPN server and your traffic is routed inside the VPN (so, for the external world, your source IP address is the one of the external interface of your OpenVPN server).

Is it true?

If no.... please give us details.

If yes, than your problem relates exactly to the OpenVPN "box" that:

- is correctly NATting your "standard" IP connections (and, in fact, you're able to succesfully connect to the remote FTP server)
- is **NOT** properly NATting the FTP protocol (that, unfortunatly, is not much NAT-friendly and, to be NATted, require special treatments).

To solve your problem you should ensure that proper kernel-module is loaded on your NAT box (OpenVPN). In my Ubuntu (and probably also on CentOS 6):

```
 # modprobe nf_conntrack_ftp
```

Such module will carefully watch all the traffic flowing along FTP "control" connection (the one you're able to establish, to authenticate and to "launch" file trasnsfers) to check what client-ports your FTP client has declared to use for file-trasfers and properly "mangling" control-connection (to "fake" such ports, by imposing NAT box ones).

In other words:

- without above modules:

  - 1) FTP client establish FTP connection to remote-server;
  - 2) FTP client want to start a file-transfer (a simple "ls"). As such...
  - 3) ...FTP client "open" a TCP port so for the FTP server to connect back to such port to transmit contents;
  - 4) ...FTP client "tell" FTP server which port has been opened, using the control-connection established at point 1)
  - 5) unfortunatly, without "special treatment", your remote FTP server, that is correctly reading/writing along the connection established at point 1), receive the couple IP/PORT specified at step 4) that contains your "private" IP address.
  - 6) so the FTP server see that control connection comes from an IP while data-connection relates to a different IP. It (correctly) dislike such a scenario, as it could lead to some reflection/DDOS scenario. As such, it sends you the error message you see.

.

- with above module loaded

  - everything is like above, except for step 5. Such step became...
  - 5) your NAT-box, thanks to the conntrack_ftp module, open an own TCP PORT (on the external interface) and gets ready to receive back FTP data-traffic on such ports. Once received it relay such traffic back to your FTP client. Also, the "control-connection" is mangled, so to replace the couple IP/PORT sent by your client with the IP/PORT of the NAT-box.
  - ...and thanks to this, everything should work smoothly :-) (...or, at least, I hope).

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I am on vacation now and will test your solution in a few days. I will mark your answer as correct if it works, otherwise give more details. :-)